# Installing Glassfish 3 on Mac OS X 10.8.2 fails in Domain Info setup

Tags: macos, installation, glassfish-3

I am a Glassfish newbie, though a Java and Unix veteran.  I am running the shell script to install Java EE 6 SDK, including Glassfish 3 on my Mac.

```
bash-3.2# sh java_ee_sdk-6u4-unix.sh
```

Everything goes along fine until I get to the Domain Info screen.  I am sticking with the default info (except for passwords):

```
Domain Name: domain1
Admin Port: 4848     <- I have verified with netstat that both ports are free
Http Port: 8080      <-
Username: admin
Password: xxxxxxxxxxxx
Service Name: domain1Service
+ Start domain after creation
```

When I click Next, I get 2 error dialogs that tell me the following:

```
Admin Port: Host name not found
Http Port: Host name not found
```

Does anyone know how to get past this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was relatively simple.  I had to add the hostname configured with MacOS Settings as an alias for localhost into my /etc/hosts file.  I'm not sure where MacOS keeps the host name.  But the hostname command (i.e. gethostname) was returning 'airguitar', which is what Glassfish was trying to connect to.  Since it wasn't in /etc/hosts, the hostname couldn't be found.

Answer (score 2):

I confirm, I correct the same problem by changing my hostname to `localhost` using the command line hostname localhost in linux.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like something is wrong with your network config. Maybe your hosts file is missing the entry for localhost.

Check the file **/private/etc/hosts** for

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
```

You can also try to set your hostname with

```
sudo hostname localhost
```

Comment: So /etc/hosts and /private/etc/hosts are the same file (same inode according to ls -i).  It contains the right entry for localhost.  What is interesting is that the hostname command returns 'airguitar' which is the name I set for the host through the preferences (I can't find where that is stored).  I can ping localhost, but I couldn't ping airguitar until I added it to /etc/hosts.  I've seen some notes about having to set my hosts domain name on the web, but I have no idea what to set that to on a standalone MacBook Air.  It would help if I understood what Glassfish was trying to do here.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem that happens on many systems, It's happening on my linux as well. The solution is quite simple, as chuck almost got it.
Check your hosts file, on linux is under /etc/hosts. You'll probably have a file like this:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
```

Check your hostname with the command hostname

```
[root@glassfish1 opt]# hostname 
glassfish1
```

And add this host name to your hosts file like this:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4 glassfish1
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
```

this did the trick for me.